# Open vCard via intent

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I want to open vCard in android contacts via intent.
I have vCard which contains in String:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
N:Zai;Alex;
TITLE:
TEL:7867843312346
ORG:Platinum tech
URL:http://google.com
EMAIL:
END:VCARD
```

I try to open it:

```
String uri = adapter.getItem(position).getVcard().toString();
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(adapter.getItem(position).getResult().toString()),"text/x-vcard");
startActivity(i);
```

but it crashes with Log:

08-24 12:18:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11811): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 12:18:27.686: E/AndroidRuntime(11811): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=BEGIN:VCARD

Answer (score 1):

When you set the data for your intent, it has to be a proper Uri, not just a Uri.parse of your vCard. But have no fear, because it's possible to put your vCard into a Uri without having to create a file. You can encode the vCard with Base64 (which Android has built-in conveniently, so import android.util.Base64) and plop that in as the Uri, like this:

```
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("data:text/x-vcard;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(theStringContainingYourVcard.getBytes()),"text/x-vcard");
```

Comment: This is actually a neat solution, however if I want to send it to another app like gmail it says file not found and doesn't attach anything to mail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the uri should point to a file uri .
`Uri.parse` will not know how to parse the vcard string that you are passing. Create a file with Vcard data and then use Uri.fromFile(file) and then use this uri in setDataAndType

Comment: Atleast the code in contacts app does not support using anything other than file uri